# QT connect crash using signal accepted

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with my Qt code. I wanted to write an program which are taking a coordinates of point and then that point is drawing in point with that coordinates. My program doesn't have any errors or warnings when i built it but it's crashing at start(MainWindow doesn't show). This is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include < QApplication >

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow win;
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QAction>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>

#include "addpoint.h"

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QToolBar *AddToolbar;
    QAction *AddPointAction;

    AddPoint *AddPointDialog;



    QLineEdit *x;


public:
    MainWindow();

    void createToolbar();
    void createActionAdd();

signals:

public slots:
    void PointClicked();
    void DialogAccepted();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

    createActionAdd();
    createToolbar();

    connect(AddPointAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(PointClicked()));

    connect(AddPointDialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(DialogAccepted()));

    setMinimumSize(480, 320);
}

/**/
void MainWindow::createToolbar()
{
    AddToolbar = new QToolBar;
    AddToolbar->addAction(AddPointAction);

    addToolBar(AddToolbar);
}

/**/
void MainWindow::createActionAdd()
{
    AddPointAction = new QAction("Add Road", this);

    x = new QLineEdit(this);
    x->setFixedSize(100, 30);
    x->move(100, 100);
}

/**/
void MainWindow::PointClicked()
{
    AddPointDialog = new AddPoint(this);
    AddPointDialog->setModal(true);

    AddPointDialog->exec();
}

/**/
void MainWindow::DialogAccepted()
{
    x->setText("abc");
}
```

addpoint.h

```
#ifndef ADDPOINT_H
#define ADDPOINT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>

class AddPoint : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLabel *XpointL;
    QLineEdit *XPoint;
    QPushButton *OKButton;


public:
    AddPoint(QWidget *parent);
    void createButton();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // ADDPOINT_H
```

addpoint.cpp

```
#include "addpoint.h"

AddPoint::AddPoint(QWidget *parent) :QDialog(parent)
{
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

    createButton();

    connect(OKButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(accept()));

    setMinimumSize(320, 240);
}

/**/
void AddPoint::createButton()
{
    XpointL = new QLabel("Point X:", this);
    XpointL->setFixedSize(100, 30);
    XpointL->move(10, 10);

    XPoint = new QLineEdit(this);
    XPoint->setFixedSize(180, 30);
    XPoint->move(120, 10);

    OKButton = new QPushButton("OK", this);
    OKButton->setFixedSize(100, 30);
    OKButton->move(200, 150);

}
```

After running the program i see in aplication output lap:
"The program has unexpectedly finished."
"C:\QT\build-xxx-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\xx.exe crashed"

I note that i made some experiments with this code and i saw that i have problem with signal accpeted() at mainwindow.cpp. I don't know what can i do with this problem. I hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddPointDialog` is uninitialized pointer, it does not yet point to valid `AddPoint` in `MainWindow`'s constructor. You cannot call `connect` on that. Its value will change later, when you do `AddPointDialog = new AddPoint(this);` and only then will you be able to call `connect`.

Simply, you should move your `connect` call to `void MainWindow::PointClicked()` after you've initialized your pointer. I'd also make `AddPointDialog` local to that function and store it on the stack (you don't use it anywhere else and you're leaking memory).

The code would be:

```
void MainWindow::PointClicked()
{
    AddPoint AddPointDialog(this);
    AddPointDialog.setModal(true);
    connect(&AddPointDialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(DialogAccepted()));
    AddPointDialog.exec();
}
```